# Issue when attempting to draw fireworks from GUI

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

I have two classes one called Userinterface and the other a Canvas I need the user to be able to enter the values of a velocity, angle, and time to be able to render fireworks onto the Canvas. However when I use the button to fire what grabs the values of the JTextFields, the Canvas won't repaint(). Nothing will happen no matter what value I enter I defined the x and y in another class but the getters and setters won't produce any value.

**Why isn't my shape drawn on the Canvase when I call `repaint()`?**

```
public class Userinterface extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static String str= "0";
    private static String str2= "0";
    private static String str3= "0";
    private JTextField angle= new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel alabel= new JLabel("Angle");
    private JTextField velocity= new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel vlabel= new JLabel("Velocity");
    private JButton Actionbutton= new JButton("launch");
    private JTextField time= new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel tlabel= new JLabel ("Time of fuse (s)");
    static int a;
    static int b;
    static int c;
    static int x;
    static int y;

    Userinterface(){
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(time);
        add(tlabel);
        add (angle);
        add(alabel);
        add (velocity);
        add(vlabel);
        add(Actionbutton);
        Actionbutton.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource()==Actionbutton) {
        str=angle.getText();
        str2=velocity.getText();
        str3=time.getText();
        a=Integer.parseInt(str);
        b=Integer.parseInt(str2);
        c=Integer.parseInt(str3);
        repaint();  // ISSUE: Canvas does not repaint here
    }   
}

public static int findx() {
    x=Fire_WorkMath.calculatex(b, c, a);
    return x;
}

public static int findy() {
    y=Fire_WorkMath.calculatey(b, c, a);
    return y;
}

public class Canvas extends JPanel {

    Userinterface one= new Userinterface();
    int ang;
    int time;
    int y;
    int x;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Canvas() {

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        x=Userinterface.findx();
        y=Userinterface.findy();
        g.drawLine(0, 0, x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `actionPerformed` method isn't updating the properties of the `Canvas` (really bad name by the way) so nothing has changed.  The instance of `Userinterface` in `Canvas` also has nothing to do with the instance that the user is interacting with. And `static` is not your friend

Comment: Thanks for the help MadProgrammer. I am sort of new to UI and do you have any suggestions to allow the actionPerformed to update the properties of Canvas (also I know the name sucks).

Comment: Use a model to pass data between the two, as demonstrated below ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing state between objects can sometimes be, complicated.  At the very basic level, what you want to do is pass the same instance of the object to which they rely on.

In this, you will want to set up a "model" which can be shared between the two classes...

```
public class FireworkModel {

    private int angle;
    private int velocity;
    private int time;

    private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners;

    public FireworkModel() {
        changeListeners = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
        for (ChangeListener listener : changeListeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
    }

    public void setAngle(int angle) {
        this.angle = angle;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    public void setVelocity(int velocity) {
        this.velocity = velocity;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
        fireStateChanged();
    }

    public int getAngle() {
        return angle;
    }

    public int getVelocity() {
        return velocity;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public int findx() {
        return Fire_WorkMath.calculatex(getVelocity(), getTime(), getAngle());
    }

    public int findy() {
        return Fire_WorkMath.calculatey(getVelocity(), getTime(), getAngle());
    }

}
```

Now, because in your example, neither the `UserInterface` or `Canvas` classes actually talk directly to each other, the model sets up a "observer pattern", which is used to notify interested parties that the state of the model has changed.

You will also note that the `findx/y` methods have also been moved here, this way they are easily accessible to those parties that need them.

Next, we change the `Canvas` (which I've renamed to `FireworksPane` since there is a `Canvas` class in the SDK) to make use of this model...

```
public class FireworksPane extends JPanel {

    private FireworkModel model;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public FireworksPane(FireworkModel model) {
        this.model = model;
        model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    public FireworkModel getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int x = getModel().findx();
        int y = getModel().findy();
        g.drawLine(0, 0, x, y);
    }
}
```

And finally, we update the `UserInterface` to also make use of the model...

```
public class Userinterface extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JTextField angle = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel alabel = new JLabel("Angle");
    private JTextField velocity = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel vlabel = new JLabel("Velocity");
    private JButton Actionbutton = new JButton("launch");
    private JTextField time = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel tlabel = new JLabel("Time of fuse (s)");

    private FireworkModel model;

    Userinterface(FireworkModel model) {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        add(time);
        add(tlabel);
        add(angle);
        add(alabel);
        add(velocity);
        add(vlabel);
        add(Actionbutton);
        Actionbutton.addActionListener(this);
        this.model = model;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == Actionbutton) {
            String str = angle.getText();
            String str2 = velocity.getText();
            String str3 = time.getText();
            int angle = Integer.parseInt(str);
            int velocity = Integer.parseInt(str2);
            int time = Integer.parseInt(str3);

            model.setAngle(angle);
            model.setVelocity(velocity);
            model.setTime(time);
        }
    }
}
```

Both classes will need the SAME instance of the model passed to them, if you expect this to work...

```
FireworkModel model = new FireworkModel();
Userinterface userinterface = new Userinterface(model);
FireworksPane fireworksPane = new FireworksPane(model);
// Setup the remaining UI
```

Comment: Thank you for all the help I understand UI much better now